# Multi vendor + add product - force to choose only 1 category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category-tree, multi-vendor

So I'm trying to make it so that the vendors can only add their product to one category from the checklist category tree (I'm using CEDCommerce's multi vendor extension).

I'm sort of new to Magento still, so I'm not sure exactly how I would go about starting. I figured I would need to add some extra javascript in the `list.phtml` but I also see a reference to a script named `decorateTable('my-products-table);`

Just wondering if I'm on the right track. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you’re on the right track, you can add Java Script and restrict the user to one category.  After that you need to apply restriction in product save function in controller or model.